# dropdown with autocomplete function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following function which populates a dropdown menu with a list of cities (coming from the url in json), I now need to add an autocomplete function which will help the user when typing in the name of the city.

How can I make a dropwdown with an autocomplete function? What's the best way for this?

```
function CitiesList (){
 $.getJSON(location.href+'ru/getCities/', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    console.log(len);
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $('.select_cities select').append(html);
 });
}
```

Comment: Check on the jQuery UI autocomplete widget.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many plugins available. You can use [this](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin. And call it as follows

```
$('select').chosen();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F4rNg/)